# ASP.Net Membership provider in WCF (WebHttpBinding)

Tags: wcf, web-services, asp.net-membership, wcf-binding

I'm developping a **WPF** application that needs authentification. I want to use the **client application services** to use the **ASP.Net Membership Provider** (see this [link](http://aspalliance.com/1596_Client_Application_Services__Part_2.7) if you don't know what I'm talking about). Actually, I made my own provider based on the MembershipProvider. It works perfectly with a ASP.Net projet.

But now, I don't want my authentification to be hosted in a ASP.Net projet anymore, but to be in WCF.

So, I did a **WCF service** and used a **WebHttpBinding**. Everything is ok, until the login is entered. The call is made to the service, no doubt about it, but nothing happens. In fact, it's like the call has been made but isn't *served*. 
I can confirm it because I used the service trace viewer to log all the messages to the service.

Eventually, I receive a timeout with the message :

> The incoming HTTP request's URI 'http://localhost:21200/Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd/Login' does not match any service operation.

It's like if the Provider isn't taking the call or receive it. I really don't know where to look. I've done my research but I did'nt find similar examples. Here's my settings :

**1. Config file for the Membership Provider** (working in a ASP.NET project)

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <authenticationService enabled="true" />
    <roleService enabled="true" />
  </webServices>
</scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms" />
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
  <membership defaultProvider="FooMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="FooMembershipProvider" type="Foo.Web.Security.FooMembershipProvider, Foo.Web" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
```

**2. Config file for my application, section service** (working if I use the ASP.NET project)

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WebBehavior">
        <webHttp />
        <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WebBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>


  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttpMode">
        <security mode="None" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpMode">
        <security mode="None" />
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"
           name="Foo.Security.Business.Manager.Wcf.Host.SecurityManager">

      <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="Foo.Security.Business.Contract.ISecurityContract"
              behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpMode" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:21200" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**3. Config file for my application, section call of the service** (working if I use the ASP.NET project)

```
<membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
   <providers>
     <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider"  type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
         serviceUri="http://localhost:21200/Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd"
         credentialsProvider="Foo.Windows.LoginWindow, Foo.Windows" />

     <add name="FooMembershipProvider"
         type="Foo.Security.Business.Provider.FooMembershipProvider, Foo.Security.Business"
         serviceUri="http://localhost:21200/Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd"
         credentialsProvider="Foo.Windows.LoginWindow, Foo.Windows" />
   </providers>
 </membership>
 <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
   <providers>
     <add name="ClientRoleProvider"
         type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
         serviceUri="http://localhost:21200/Role_JSON_AppService.axd"
         cacheTimeout="86400" />
   </providers>
 </roleManager>
```

If anyone could give me some hints where to look, it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you could try, is to use https.

In this case you are sending a password over the network in clear text. Sometimes the technology will save you, in that if you try that it will not work.

I am not sure if this is the case here, but since it is only the login that does not work, it is worth a try.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll give a try.
It would surprised me if it's working because with a classic ASP.Net project it doesn't need it.

Comment: Ok, I tried with a wsHttpBinding and I Need a certificate, which I don't own.
Any other idea ?

Comment: wshttpbinding is not the same as https. You could use IIS tools to create a self issued certificate

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584198/authentication-service-using-wcf ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

http://underground.infovark.com/2008/03/21/wcf-webhttp-binding-and-authentication/

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't work.
Anyway, we changed our mind about our authentification approach.